# Will the given code (in the description) cross join if the second table is a foreign key in the first table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that if I use `select * from table1, table2` the results will be a cross join between the two tables. But what if the second table's primary key is foreign key in the first table, will the result still be a cross join?

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have no join, the result is the catersian product